# Edge Detection in Image Processing using VHDL

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection

I am very new to the image processing field. My question is that
1) In edge detection, which filter is used for real time purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Two commonly used filter for edge detection are laplacian filter and sobel edge detector. Depending on your application, you can choose either of those